# list is not getting updated in helper function

Tags: python

I have written below code to find root to leaf paths of binary tree. But this code is not updating `op` list variable. when I use `op.extend(value)`
inside helper function it extend the list but not sure why its not appending the list? I am expecting `op` as a list of paths and path is itself a list. e.g.:

`[[1,2,5],[1,3]]`

## python 2.7 code:

```
def treepaths(root):
  op=[]
  currPath=[]
  
  def _path(root):
    if not root:
      return
    
    currPath.append(root.val)
    _path(root.left)
    
    if not root.left and not root.right:
      op.append(currPath)
    _path(root.right)
    currPath.pop()
  
  _path(root)
  return op
```

Comment: I guess that currPath.pop() is removing the path from op. Try to comment this line?

Comment: I see the logic in your code.  I can see how to make it read a little better and be a bit more efficient, but it seems like it should work.  Can you provide code to build a sample tree and show the output and also give us your expected output?  In other words, can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what your problem is.  @J.K. was onto something. The problem is that you're putting a REFERENCE to **currPath** into **op** whenever you reach a leaf.  Since that is a reference, when you later manipulate **currPath** further, that changes all of the referenced objects (that same object) that you've pushed to **op** too.  And since at the end of your traversal of the tree, **currPath** ends up empty, so do all the referenced objects inside **op**.  All you need to do to fix this is COPY the list into 'op' each time.  So:

```
op.append(currPath)
```

should be:

```
op.append(list(currPath))
```

and I think you'll get the result you expect.

Here's a complete example I put together.  In the future, this is the sort of thing we'd like to see posted as a question:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, left = None, right = None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

root = Node("A",
    Node("B",
        Node("C",
             Node("D"))),
    Node("F",
         Node("G",
              Node("H")),
         Node("I",
              None,
              Node("J")))
    )


def treepaths(root):
    op = []
    currPath = []

    def _path(root):
        if not root:
            return

        currPath.append(root.val)
        _path(root.left)

        if not root.left and not root.right:
            op.append(list(currPath))
        _path(root.right)
        currPath.pop()

    _path(root)
    return op

print(treepaths(root))
```

Which results in:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'F', 'G', 'H'], ['A', 'F', 'I', 'J']]
```

Without the fix, you get:

```
[[], [], []]
```

Comment: Thanks Steve! Still I wonder how code works fine with op.extend(currPath)

Comment: Glad I could help!  You will get different results with op.extend().  That would add each item in **currPath** individually to **op** rather than adding the list itself.  So you would end up in that case with a list of just strings, not a list of lists of strings.  And that "works" because you have to copy the individual elements to add them to **ops**, so the "copying a reference" thing doesn't apply.